# Access a git repository of another user

Tags: github

I'm a new Git user and i have to look at the code of a project. the person who called me for that gave me his git access codes (email and password).
For sure, I tried to enter them directly in github website login form, but it ask me to enter a code sent to his own email...

it is for a work, and I don't know what to do... should I ask him to give me this famous verification code?
I got the feeling it is not very secure to process that way.

can you tell me how can I acces the repo with this type of information? the problem is that it is not an invitation to collaborate, but just email and password. Should I disconnect my own git account with my windows terminal to enter his own email and password?

thanks for your help!

For the moment, the owner of this site doesn't answer so that I can't work on his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can login from your GitHub and then go to that person profile (by searching by username) and then view their repository. Then you can see that repository's code. For this solution, the repository should be public.
[image]